# ajax search function called twice using $(window).bind( 'hashchange', function(e)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm working on ajax search.ajax function is called on onblur event.below is sample code.

```
function search_ajax(sh_val,sh_act)
{
    ....some search code.....
    window.location.hash = sh_val+'@'+sh_act;

}
```

I have made one other function for restore the serch using hash value from url when click on browser back or forward button.this work well for back and forward button.

```
$(window).bind( 'hashchange', function(e) {
var page=location.hash.slice(1)
if (page!="" && page!="p")
    {
        search_ajax(page,'catsh');
    }
    return false;
 });
```

but i am facing issue when i am search ajax search function is called twice. $(window).bind( 'hashchange') is also called when i am searching.is there any way to call the above function only for browser back and forward button or any other solution ?

how can i resolve this issue?

I would appreciate anykind of help..

Comment: Hello Jimmy,No one expert here?Please provide your input here..so jimmy will be helpful.

Comment: I expected but I think I will not get any solution from here As this question is beyond stack overflow users capability..

Answer (score 2):

maybe I don't understand well, but why did you bind hashchange function to window??? It doesn't make any sence. I have similar searching function in my own apps. It is not that complicated. My search function is (lets say) same as yours:

```
function search_ajax(sh_val,sh_act)
{
    ....some search code.....
    window.location.hash = sh_val+'@'+sh_act;
}
```

The another one is performed once per page load:

```
(function() {
var page=location.hash.slice(1)
if (page!="" && page!="p")
    {
        search_ajax(page,'catsh');
    }
    return false;
})();
```

So, if you click search button, then search function is called. Hash is changed. One step into browser history is added.

Then another search, another step in history is added.

Then back button. Page loaded again, so annonymous function is performed. Hash is detected, so search is performed. And hash is changed, but becouse hash is same as before, so link is same, then no duplicite step is added into history.

Comment: Just realized, that this is a good solution too. There is no need to bind the event...

Comment: i am using  bind hashchange because i need to call ajax function without page reaload for browser back and forward button.

Comment: Think i will search 'cable' then url will be www.xyz.com/test.php#cable@search_key.then the result of 'cable' will be displayed . then i will search 'wire' withour refresh the page then url will be www.xyz.com/test.php#wire@search_key. now when i hit back button then url will change and it will first one of cable serach 'www.xyz.com/test.php#cable@search_key'. ehen the bind hashchange function called and display result using 'cable' word from url.

Comment: but currenty issue is that bind hashchange is also called on normal search when type any search word in search text box.

Comment: Thanx @WindKiller for your answer but i need to call it without Page loaded.

Comment: Then I will try to make better solution ;) Im pretty sure that it can be done.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a semaphore:

```
var searching = false;

function search_ajax(sh_val, sh_act) {
    searching = true;
    ....some search code.....
    window.location.hash = sh_val + '@' + sh_act;
    searching = false;
}

$(window).bind('hashchange', function (e) {
    if (searching) 
        return false;
    var page = location.hash.slice(1);
    if (page != "" && page != "p") {
        search_ajax(page, 'catsh');
    }
    return false;
});
```